# Nestjs parse uploaded pdf to json without saving the file in the directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to upload a pdf file then I need to parse it using pdf2json without saving the file in the directory but pdf2json requests a directory path in loadPDF. any idea what can I do, please?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json

```js
@Post('getFields')
      @UseInterceptors(AzureStorageFileInterceptor('file'))
        @UploadedFile() file?: UploadedFileMetadata){
  
        if (!file || Object.keys(file).length === 0 ||file.constructor !== Object) {
            throw UtilError.createErrorError('Missing file.');
        }
        const pdfParser = new PDFParser(file);
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError) );
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
            fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, './../../../../src/entities/skiplino/form/F1040EZ.json'), JSON.stringify(pdfData), function(){ console.log("done!") }
            );
        });
         return await pdfParser.loadPDF(./../file);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you'd be against just giving it a path that's temporary, uploading the result to azure and then deleting the file and/or temporary directory again? Or is it simply not possible to provide a path (filesystem permissions, for example)?

Comment: I tried but pdfParser.loadPDF required directory path didn't accept the azure url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `pdfParser.parseBuffer(pdfBuffer);` and pass in the file buffer.

You'll need to use the built in [File Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) instead of the `AzureStorageFileInterceptor`